# Remove RecyclerView scroll effects

Tags: android, scroll, effect, android-recyclerview

I have two `RecyclerView` inside my `NavigationDrawer`. Both have the blue scroll effects.

How can I remove this effect in both `RecyclerViews`?

I tried changing: `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` to `false`, but it remove scroll effects. (What is the effect of this method?)

[image: Link to an image of the problem]

Answer (score 473, accepted):

Add this to your layout:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

So:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: only problem with this is that the fadingEdge option is disabled

Comment: There are also value "ifContentScrolls", if you want to show effect, when list is longer than view

Comment: wow man it so useful very very thank you for your help....

Comment: This is the correct answer 100%

Answer (score 27):

And in Java you would do

```
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
```

or in Kotlin

```
recyclerView.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
```