# Remove Fade effect(blue shadow from header and footer) in Listview, RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am looking for a solution to remove the shadow effect which appears at the header and footer part of `ListView` and `RecyclerView`.

Please help me regarding this if there are any solution available. I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: It's not really a fade effect. It's called overscroll.

Comment: @Mike...Thanks for your reply....would you please provide solution link here?

Comment: There's a link at the top of your question. Here's another with an answer shows it a little better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27724923.