# Substitute for RecyclerView if I do not need the scrollable functionality?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

New to android java and trying to figure this out. If I want to have an array adapter to display a list of images horizontally, what options do I have other than RecyclerView?

Basically, I am making a Chinese mahjong game. I want to display thumbnails horizontally that needs `onClickListener` functionality. The screen needs to NOT be scrollable. A `LinearLayout` doesn't seem to have an arrayadapter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove RecyclerView scroll effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724923/remove-recyclerview-scroll-effects)

Comment: @Biscuit that question addresses specifically removing the overscroll glow effect, which, while similar, is not quite the same as the issue here.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable RecyclerView scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

No Layout has something similar to the arrayadapter, if the amount of images don't change I would suggest putting them inside of a layout as you mentioned and reference the seperate imageviews seperately

Alternatively, if the amount is dynamic I'd suggest using a ListView but disabling scrolling, for example using this:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `RecyclerView` for this (assuming you have a new enough version, though it's supported this for a couple years now)

You'd just need to create a horizontal RecyclerView and set its `android:layout_width` to `"wrap_content"`.  That will cause it to inflate all of the available items and then size itself to their total width.